# Why i get wrong amount of documents?

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to find all users (unique ids) who has done 2 events "Level 1" and "Purchase Hard"

```
x = list(db.events.distinct("uid", {"eventName": "Level 1"}) and db.events.distinct("uid", {"eventName": "Purchase Hard"}))
```

This code as a result gives around 1600 documents so as a result i should get this amount of documents. So I take documents for this with this code:

```
lel = list(db.events.aggregate(
[
    {"$match": {"eventName" : "Level 1"}},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$uid", "dateofstart": {"$addToSet": "$updated_at"}}}
]))
```

And then I try to get only documents I need like this:

```
dateoflvl1pay = list()
for players in lel:
    kost = players["_id"]
    if kost in x:
        dateoflvl1pay.append(players)
```

But as a result I get only 850 documents. Can you please help to find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a fewer documents because your **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** filter is excluding the other event "Purchase Hard". You need to include it with the other event using the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator as follows:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "eventName": { "$in": ["Level 1", "Purchase Hard"] } } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$uid", "dateofstart": { "$addToSet": "$updated_at" } } }
])
```

which you can also query for the distinct `uid` as

```
db.events.distinct("uid", { "eventName": { "$in": ["Level 1", "Purchase Hard"] } })
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I do not understand how this magic works. As I understand all "uid" in "x" are present in both "Level 1" and "Purchase Hard" so i should get all of them when i get only 1 event and then use sorting with "x" to get the same result. When I started to be wrong?

Comment: The result you get from `lel` is a subset of `x` hence the lower number of documents (850). You don't get the same results because `x` has 1600 documents and those include unique `uid` for BOTH events. `lel` only has documents with the unique `uid` for ONE event. That's the part you went wrong; your aggregation pipeline only filtered documents with that ONE event instead of TWO events.